# What factors determine the type of medal (bronze/silver/gold) for event participation?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In an event you can get a bronze, silver, or gold medal for your participation. I've been awarded gold in cases where I came in late and hardly put in any effort, and I've seen bronze when I worked my behind off.

**So my question(s):** What factors determine the type of medal awarded?

As noted in the comments it may be very hard to give a definitive answer to this question, this is why I rephrased so I'm not asking for a *formula*, but merely for *whether a factor plays a role or not* (factors like being in the area or not, participation time, doing damage, etc). If there's no official word about this, then it should still be possible to find an answer through experimentation (e.g. doing the same event twice once *with* the factor and once *without*).

**Update:** after re-reading the comment to this question I realize that this question is still a bit too broad, even after my earlier changes. There's easily 10 to 15 potential factors, and [8+ different event types](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dynamic_event#Event_indicators), making for 80 to 120 things to test for. Changing the question to be about just one event type *might* make it answerable, but would change the meaning too much. The question's interesting (at least, to me) nonetheless, so I welcome any improvements to make it more answerable. Until then, I'm voting to close as well.

---

For reference, borrowed from the [GW2 Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/), this is the medal thing I'm talking about:

[image: gold medal for an event]

On that very wiki, the section [Event Rewards, on the Dynamic Event page](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dynamic_event#Event_rewards) has a formula for the amount of karma received, but no info about how the type of medal is determined.

Has anyone experimented with the variables, measured anything, etc? Or is there official info from the makers of GW?

Comment: I don't think this question is going to be very answerable at all considering the massive variance in the type of events and how you can complete them. There's no official word from Arenanet on their participation metrics, and I doubt they're going to release that info because it would make it easier for people to game the system that way.

Comment: @FAE Agreed, answerability may be a problem. I've rephrased the question trying to improve that. I reckon it should be practically possible to determine if a factor plays a role at all or not.

Comment: I now realize the question's (unfortunately) still to broad :'(. Will also vote to close, alas.

Comment: Awwwhh.... close votes: okay, I voted so myself as well. But "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"? :'(

Answer (score 3):

The exact parameters vary between the events, so it's pretty hard to give exact values, but in my experience, it is rather easy to get Gold.

The thing to note is that the medals operate on thresholds. I.e., you must do *this much* damage to earn Bronze, *this (higher) much* to earn silver, and *very much* to earn gold.

**This means that, unfortunately, if you run around rezzing downed players, granting boons, and debuffing a boss (but *not* actually dealing damage), you are unlikely to get more than bronze, despite your help.**

If the event is to kill something, you need to kill several somethings. If instead, the event is to collect things, you darn well better collect things (killing them won't give you more than bronze).

And lastly, Bronze seems to be very easy to achieve. I've sometimes earned credit from Dynamic Events I didn't know were even going on, simply because I was in the proper area, or killed an NPC who was tangentially related to the event.

Comment: I have once gotten a Gold for an event I wasn't even aware I was a part of. I say this to reinforce the fact that the "threshold" vary greatly depending on the event. However usually I would randomly get a Bronze as I walk through zones.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I've voted to close my own question, but it's still good that this answer is here for anyone who stumbles on the question through searches.