# Does the quality of the medal effect loot quality?

Tags: guild-wars-2

When I complete an event that rewards a chest/any loot, does the quality of the medal received (Bronze, Silver, Gold) affect the quality of the loot received? Or does the medal only affect the amount of EXP/Karma received?

Comment: Duplicate, maybe? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84491/what-factors-determine-the-type-of-medal-bronze-silver-gold-for-event-particip

Comment: @fbueckert Related for sure, but I am more asking the quality of the loot, not conditions you have to meet to get a specific medal.

Comment: Heh.  Missed that entirely.  My bad.

Comment: While it may be a coincidence, a friend and I did the same event at the same time where he got gold and I got silver; his loot was rare, mine was not.

Comment: @Fluttershy I really hope its not coinidence. I mean the Karma is great and all but I would love to see that the loot scales too.

Comment: I've noticed that the player's actual level affects it.

Comment: Good question! +1  As the answerer said, I would assume 'no' from experience.  Numerous boss fights would suggest so, but this is anecdotal...

Answer (score 2):

From experience in doing the various dragon events, no. Medal quality does not affect loot from the treasure chest after the end of the events.

I have got rares from events where i only achieved a bronze medal and vice-versa.

I don't think there is any real and concrete evidence to prove this at this point in time though.